# Breeze 1.4.4 throws an error in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, breeze

When I include breeze.debug.js (1.4.4) into a project through a script tag and run it in IE8. It gives me the following error:

```
Object doesn't support this property or method  breeze.debug.js, line 801 character 9
```

It happens on line 801

```
function exec(self) {
    // clear off last one if null 
    var contexts = self._contexts;
    if (contexts[contexts.length - 1] == null) {
        contexts.pop();
    }
    if (contexts.length === 0) {
        return undefined;
    }
    return contexts.some(function(context) {
        return context.fn(context, self.v);
    });
}
```

On the last line (801), `contexts.some` is undefined, which causes the error.

I also tried http://todo.breezejs.com/ with IE8 and it did not work either. You can get IE8 virtual machines from http://www.modern.ie/ and run it in Virtual PC or Virtual Box to test the issue.

Works fine in IE9.

Can you please fix the problem? I'd like to run breeze on IE8, as it is [officially supported](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/prerequisites).

Comment: "Can you please fix the problem? I'd like to run breeze on IE8, as it is officially supported." Love it, if I were IdeaBlade I would answer with "Can you please fix your problems reading the docs, where it clearly states you need to shim"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have pointed out; Breeze for IE8 needs the ES5 shim.  Documented on the Breeze website  [here](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/prerequisites)

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you're including [ES5-shim / sham](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) in your page load.